# TCP - Sending and Receiving TCP/IP Data

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, ip

I have a client and a server communicating to one another over a standard TCP connection.

The server is configured to send data in consistently sized chunks of x bytes. The client is also configured to receive data in chunks of x bytes (i.e. the client expects that the call to the TCP stack to receive x bytes will be successful unless the connection with the remote end has failed).

Is it OK to base my TCP based protocol on the assumption above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deja vu [Will TCPStream read block until all data is received.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322147/will-tcpstream-read-block-until-all-data-is-recieved-in-send-message/6322227#6322227)

I realize it looks a little different but at the core they are very similar questions.

Don't make assumptions about packet sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure that the answers in response to that question are complete. "Proper form" aside. TCP has strict rules governing reliability and flow control. If the sender sends 20 bytes in "one hit" surely the receiver side should not be allowed to read any of those 20 bytes until all have been received and reconstructed in the correct order? and; therefore, a protocol contract based on pre-negotiated chunk size should be OK to assume should it not?

Comment: No.  It is a stream.  I might write 100 bytes and that could translate into 100 1-byte reads.  Or 2 50-byte reads.  Or any other combination.  It is not packet based.  See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketmessageboundary.aspx) for additional discussion.

Comment: That same article states the following: 

"The easiest but most costly way to solve the TCP message problem is to create a protocol that always transmits messages of fixed size. By setting all messages to the same size, the receiving TCP program can know without doubt when the entire message has been received from the remote device."

And so making assumptions on packet sizes is OK provided it is followed by both sides of the communication. Remember my protocol does not use variable length data chunks - it is always the same.

Comment: What it means is that if a message is always size X, then when the receiver has X it knows that it has a complete message.  But it does not mean that the receiver will get X in a single read.  The receiver may need to do X 1-byte reads to get the entire message.  See the difference?  Basically if the size is fixed the receiver just knows intrinsically when it has received a complete message without needing to include the message length in the message or use special data markers in the stream to indicate end of message.

Comment: I have read nothing to indicate what you are saying to be true. If A sends 20 bytes, and B receives all 20 bytes before it is made available in B's TCP buffer, then calling recv(20 bytes) should never fail unless a communication problem has occurred? 

Sorry, about being stubborn with this one I am attempting to locate any part of the spec which definitely answers this one way or the other at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can say.  [#20](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/lame-list.html) on the list? I used to support a TCP/IP development kit and the assumption you are making was hand's down the #1 cause of buggy TCP applications. What makes it worse is that you might exchange thousands or even millions of messages without issue, but it just means you're lucky to that point.  At some point the network will hiccup and things will go awry if you ever assume TCP to be anything more than a byte stream.

Comment: Thanks for the dialog ribram. Several other articles have convinced me of your answer's correctness.

Comment: TCP simply has no mechanism to 'glue' bytes together.

Answer (score 3):

No.  TCP is a stream based protocol.  You cannot guarantee "chunks" unless you handle the chunking yourself at the application level.  TCP as a protocol will not insure this for you.